# Faster than Time Machine for Backup

Tags: time-machine, backup

I want to do a full backup of my Mac to an external disk AS FAST AS POSSIBLE.  Does that mean I should use something other than Time Machine or set some settings?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your full usage scenario is. For a one-off full image Time Machine is not very well suited, you are better of with using

- the disk imaging functionality in Disk Utility
- [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)
- [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com)

If you are looking for having a full image of your drive updated regularly, fast and hassle-free, Time Machine is a good way to do that. The initial backup will just take a while longer, the incremental ones will be rather fast.

Comment: and rsync? is there any compelling reason to use SuperDuper or CCC over rsync?

Comment: AIUI CCC's sync feature actually uses a specially updated & patched version of rsync -- see [CCC author Mike Bombich's rsync notes](http://afp548.com/static/mactips/rsync.html). I'm not sure about speed, but I think it does a slightly better job of preserving file attributes than the Apple-supplied rsync version.